# How to access delegate object properties in groovy?

Tags: groovy

This is my example code for this question:

```
class Person {
    String fullName
}

def myClosure = {
    fullName = "Chakroun Anas"
}

Person person = new Person()
myClosure.delegate = person
myClosure()
println(person.fullName)
```

This is the output :

```
null
```

So is it possible to access the delegate object properties from the closure ? if so then how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this (using [this page](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2009/11/groovy-goodness-setting-closures.html) as a reference):

```
class Person {
    String fullName
}

def myClosure = {
    fullName = "Chakroun Anas"
}

Person person = new Person()

myClosure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
myClosure.delegate = person
myClosure()

println(person.fullName)
```